# Pb with JavaFx progressbar behavior

Tags: java, javafx

The very first moment I start a task bound with my progress bar, the latter begins and rewind then restarts, this time according to my counter (as I expected). This unwanted effect is very subtle but visible nevertheless.

Here is my test code below:

```
private void startButtonEventHandler(ActionEvent event) {
 Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() {
  @Override
  protected Task<Void> createTask() {

   Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
     public Void call() throws Exception {
      for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
       // Long running task ...
       Thread.sleep(500);
       updateProgress(i, 10);
      }

      return null;
     }
    };

    progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    return task;
   }
  };

  service.start();
}
```

The progressbar is determinate :

```
progressBar = new ProgressBar(0.0F);
progressBar.setPrefWidth(200);
```

Update: I realized that the progressBar starts in undeterminate mode at the beginning and then after the first call to updateProgress() method it switches to the determinate mode. Is that a bug or a feature ?

Comment: Did you try to bind the progress bar's progress property to the progress property of the service before starting the service instead of `progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());`?

Comment: Yes I did but it not solve this weird behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The task's initial progress is `-1` (i.e. indeterminate). (This makes sense, since by default the task has no idea how long it will take...) So when you bind the progress of the progress bar to the progress of the task, the progress bar becomes indeterminate.

Just set the progress of the task to 0 when it is created:

```
protected Task<Void> createTask() {

    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {

        {
            updateProgress(0, 10);
        }     

        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
             for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                 // Long running task ...
                 Thread.sleep(500);
                 updateProgress(i, 10);
             }

             return null;
        }
     };

     progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
     return task;
}
```

Comment: Oops not yet ... still that annoying effect.

Comment: Sometimes it does ok sometimes the undeterminate state shows up (I'd say once every 2 try).

Comment: I tried your update it didn't change anything. In the meantime I tried this code on my home computer (same JDK 8.121 64 underneath) and this time there is no visible indeterminate state visible no matter how many times I run it. My home computer has a Core i7 I7-7700K Kaby Lake processor inside and my work computer runs on an older Core i5 generation, I believe this would explain the whole difference. Nevertheless, I tend to believe that this is a JavaFX bug that could remain unnoticed with nowadays fast processors.